# convert several factors where the levels appear as numbers to a numeric vector

Tags: r, date, lapply, numeric

I have a dataset which has several variables for years of birth (recorded as factors).
I want to convert the factor variables to numeric, but keeping the levels. I can do this individually using the command:

```
data$yrbrn1 <- as.numeric(levels(data$yrbrn1))[data$yrbrn1]
```

However, I want to do the same thing for multiple variables.

The head of my data is (first eight variables):

```
   yrbrn1  yrbrn2  yrbrn3  yrbrn4  yrbrn5  yrbrn6  yrbrn7  yrbrn8
1   2012    1949    1955     NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
2   2012    1983    1951    1956    1989    1995    2003     2005
3   2012    1946    1946    1978     NA      NA      NA       NA 
4   2012     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
5   2012    1953    1959    1980    1985    1991    2008     2011
6   2012    1938     NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
```

I have tried:

```
data[,2:ncol(data)] <- lapply(data[,2:ncol(data)], as.numeric(levels([,2:ncol(data)]))[,2:ncol(data)]
```

but I get an error.

Comment: Have a look of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think that you want to use `as.numeric`. Look at the results of that on any one column and you will see what is wrong. Instead you need to use `as.character`
first.

Also, `data` is the name of an R function, so I am going to assume that the data is called `DATA` instead. You should get what you want from

```
 sapply(DATA, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```